# higher dimensional arrays with runge_kutta4

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to solve a system of coupled differential equations using **boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta4**. It is a 3D lattice system so it would be natural for me (and convenient) to work with 3D arrays. Is there a way for runge_kutta4 to work with user defined data structures or boost multi_array ?

Answer (score 2):

In principle this is possible. odeint provideds a mechanism to use custom data structures - algebras and operations. Have a look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html). Either you use one of the existing algebras and try to adapt your data structure to work with this algebra. Or you implement your own algebra and instantiate the Runge Kutta stepper with it.

You might also want to have a look at a library like Eigen, Mtl4, boost.ublas, or Armadillo. They might have data types for higher order tensors. For example Eigen works very well with odeint.

Comment: Armadillo has the [Cube](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube) class, which is essentially a 3rd order tensor (aka "3D matrix")

Comment: I tried using boost::multi_array even with 2 dimensions but it does not seems to work.

Comment: @headmyshoulder Could you provide a simple example using Eigen::Matrix< std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>? I am trying to run a test but I get a lot of errors. I think that is the main one:                                                                                              **error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, -1, -1>&)’**